# FLEX: wrap buttons in the HBox, instead of seeing scrolling bar

Tags: apache-flex

I have a HBox and I dynamically add Buttons into it. I want to distribute such buttons horizontally, however I would like to place there on more rows if there is not anymore horizontal space, instead of seeing the scrolling bar.

How can I do that?

```
  <mx:HBox id="tagsPopup" visible="false" horizontalAlign="center" width="100">
        <mx:LinkButton label="Tag1" />
        <mx:LinkButton label="Tag2" />
        <mx:LinkButton label="Tag3" />
        <mx:LinkButton label="Tag4" />      
    </mx:HBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBox renders only on one horizontal row. Use a [Tile](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/Tile.html) for what you want.